# Get difference in days for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df

```
      group1      group2     date
1     a           b          2017-01-01
2     b           c          2017-01-05
3     d           b          2017-01-07
4     c           a          2017-01-10
5     a           d          2017-01-15
```

df expect

```
      group1      group2     grp1_diff_days      grp2_diff_days
1     a           b          NaN                 NaN
2     b           c          4                   NaN
3     d           b          NaN                 2
4     c           a          5                   9
5     a           d          5                   8
```

I want to get the difference in days for a group and then put that value in their respective column ['grp**i**_diff_days'] regardless of if they were from another group before.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup*** (Assuming, your `date` column is already `datetime`)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group1': {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'd', 4: 'c', 5: 'a'},
 'group2': {1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'b', 4: 'a', 5: 'd'},
 'date': {1: pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
  2: pd.Timestamp('2017-01-05 00:00:00'),
  3: pd.Timestamp('2017-01-07 00:00:00'),
  4: pd.Timestamp('2017-01-10 00:00:00'),
  5: pd.Timestamp('2017-01-15 00:00:00')}})
```

---

```
s = df.set_index('date').stack().rename('value').reset_index(0)

d = pd.DataFrame(s.groupby('value').date.diff().values.reshape(-1, 2),
                 columns=['g1diff', 'g2diff'],
                 index=df.index)

df.join(d)
```

```
  group1 group2       date g1diff g2diff
1      a      b 2017-01-01    NaT    NaT
2      b      c 2017-01-05 4 days    NaT
3      d      b 2017-01-07    NaT 2 days
4      c      a 2017-01-10 5 days 9 days
5      a      d 2017-01-15 5 days 8 days
```